# How can I access a private class' atributes from a function that the constructor is taking as parameter?

Tags: c++

So I have this:

```
class Foo {
    public:
        Foo(void (*f)(Foo*));
    protected:
        int x;
};

void function(Foo *foo) {
    foo->x = 10;
}

int main () {
    Foo bar = Foo(&function);
}
```

Ideally, I would like to change through 'function' any protected attribute of Foo instance I'd want. I don't know any method of doing it since I cannot befriend that function since it is just being passed as a parameter to the constructor.

Any way I could accomplish this by keeping the same structure (I mean, by using an external function to alter Foo's protected elements when created)?

I'm writing a game engine and the idea is that Foo is a Room class and the user should write his/her own function to load up the assets to the Room. So, I don't know what the users function name will be and therefore I cannot befriend it.

Comment: Read up on "friend functions"

Comment: yeah, I know I could just befriend 'function' within the Foo class, but I'm writing a game engine and the idea is that Foo is a Room class and the user should write his/her own function to load up the assets to the Room. So, I don't know what the users function name will be and therefore I cannot befriend it.

Comment: You befriend functions by name. Functions that you befriend become parts of your interface. You cannot befriend functions by pointer. That would mean your interface is unlimited, any function can choose to become a part of it. This amounts to making everything public, as you have no control of who can do want.

Comment: Why circumvent the C++ member access rules? Almost certain you should re-evaluate your design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answers is that you can't give access to protected/private class members to external functions or classes with out explicitly giving them 'friend' access.

I propose an alternative that still fits with you current approach/structure:

```
class Room;

struct RoomAssets {
    int x;
    // ...
};

// Base class for loading Room assets
class AssetLoader {
public:
    virtual void loadAssets(RoomAssets *room) = 0;
};

class Room {

public:
    Room(AssetLoader *al) {
        RoomAssets ra;
        al->loadAssets(&ra);
        // do what ever you like with the struct values
        this->x = ra.x;
    }

protected:
    int x;
};

// A Room loader that loads 10 of each asset
class TenAssets : public AssetLoader {

public:
    void loadAssets(RoomAssets *ra) {
        ra->x = 10;
    }
};

int main() {
    TenAssets da;
    Room room(&da);
}
```

In this example there is a Room class and a `AssetLoader` class. The Room class calls the `loadAssets` method of what ever type of 'AssetLoader` was passed it.

The `AssetLoader` loads up the struct that it was passed with values and the `Room` object is free to do whatever it likes with the values.

Answer (score 1):

1) Declare x as public.

2) Write a setter function in Foo that sets x.

3) Declare function as a friend, i.e., `friend void function(Foo*);`

Comment: Doesn't making it public defeat the purpose?

Comment: I don't want to make x public but I think I'm going for the public setter function approach. Don't know how I didn't see that before... And yes, I know my design is complicated like HELL and it could probably do better, but that'll do for the moment. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to start by providing a public setX() function first and see how that goes.

You'll want to avoid making x public unless absolutely necessary, e.g. for performance reasons, and you'll only want to do after if you determine after profiling the code that your setX() function is slowing things down.

I'm not sure you'll be able to friend in this case, and you probably don't want to do that anyway.

Comment: Thanks! I think I'm going for this approach. Performance isn't a big issue for the time being, since I'm just writing a 2D gaming engine for simple games, but anyhow I'll keep that in mind.